# ASP Classic - Error 502 when running stored Procedure more than 90 second

Tags: stored-procedures, vbscript, asp-classic, timeout

As stated in the title, I have a page that calls a stored procedure.
When the data that needs to be processed isn't big which takes less than 90 second, its working fine but when the data is big that takes more than 90 second to process, after 90 second I got the error 502 page.

I assumed that that the error is referring to page timeout. So i put server.scripttimeout = 999 but the same error persists, either the server.scripttimeout not working or the error 502 page is referring to something else.

My connection string is as follows :

```
Dim con, rstx, mycmd
  Set mycmd = Server.CreateObject("adodb.command")
  Set con = Server.CreateObject ("adodb.Connection")
  con.ConnectionString = connstring
  con.connectionTimeOut=6000
  con.open
  If Err.Number = 0 Then
  mycmd.commandtimeout = 6000
  mycmd.commandtext = sql
  mycmd.commandtype = 4
  mycmd.ActiveConnection = con
  set dData=mycmd
  end if
```

I've googled about this problem to no avail. Been having this problem for a really long time now.

Anyone knows the solution? please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: EDIT : First of all, thanks alot guys for the reply, I think I might have found the solution, period. First of all, I tried using server.scripttimeout to alter the timeout which works on localhost but when I put it on our webserver, it doesn't work and so after hours of struggling I found out about Response.buffer which realy helps alot, What I did is, after 20 records of processing the server then send some sort of replies to the client so that the client isn't hanging by itself for more than 90 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thanks a lot guys for the reply, I think I might have found the solution, period. First of all, I tried using server.scripttimeout to alter the timeout which works on localhost but when I put it on our webserver, it doesn't work and so after hours of struggling I found out about Response.buffer which really helps a lot.

What I did is, after 20 records has been processed the server then send some sort of reply to the client so that the client isn't hanging by itself for more than 90 seconds waiting for response. Though I'm still googling if there is cons/downside of using response.buffer which I haven't found right now.

If anyone knows the downside/cons of response.buffer I would be grateful if you would share. Nevertheless, for now I would consider this problem as solve for now.

Thanks again guys.

PS : I'm sorry for putting the 'Edit' on the comment section, I meant to post the solution but accidentally put it under comment without noticing it after I post it.

Answer (score 0):

while changing the timeout is a good idea short term, long term, i would focus on figuring out what the exact issue is. Can you optimize your sql query to be more efficient? do you have primary keys set and are using indexes on your database?

Find the overlying cause of your problem, then decide if setting the timeouts are the strongest. My guess is it won't :)

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the reply. For now, I think i can say that my problem has been solved, see the edit on post for details. Thanks a lot sir.

Answer (score -2):

Hi connection limit set IIS for ASP

[image]

Comment: Hi sir, Thanks for the reply.. I have no access to the web server but I'll try to ask the guy that maintain it to check the setting as above. Thanks in advance..

Comment: This is an English site but the image isn't, this is against the posting policy, please correct. See [How do I deal with non-English content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/692942).

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the reply. For now, I think i can say that my problem has been solved, see the edit on post for details. Thanks a lot sir.